# Any ideas how to pass className to rendered element implicitly?

Tags: reactjs

Let me start by example

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar className="App__navbar" />
    </div>
  );
};

const Navbar = ({ className }) => {
  const rootClass = classnames('Navbar', className);

  return (
    <div className={rootClass}>
      some content...
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is a pretty common way to add extra classes to the components. It's okay, it works. But if you ask me, I would tell you that we have a problem here.

I really appreciate developer experience and IDE support. I want be able to navigate to CSS class declaration. If I use `classnames` I lose this opportunity.

So the idea to *hack* React to pass this `className` implicitly is occupied my mind. In ideal situation I will be able to navigate to both `App__navbar` and `Navbar` via `cmd+click` in my IDE.

Any ideas how this could be done?

/cc [Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov)

Comment: what IDE do you use? idk if this question is about manipulating IDE to allow you to `cmd+click` to if clicked on the `className`, is it?

Comment: Is this question really related to code or IDE?

Comment: You want the IDE to take you to the css definitions  when you click the classnames in JSX? Or you are talking about this experience in React Dev Toolbar?

Comment: Like others, I'm missing how this is about react? Are you asking for your IDE to perform a runtime evaluation of incoming arguments, without actually running the code? In the case of `const stubClass="App"; const navbarClass="navbar"; Navbar className={stubClass + "__" + navbarClass} />` would you expect the IDE to interpret that? What about conditional assignments, where the incoming values are dependent on some factors that can't be evaluated statically?

Comment: So what happens when you add `const App2 = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar className="App2__navbar" />
    </div>
  );
};` Should your editor direct you to both `App__navbar` **and** `App2__navbar`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.5 by doing the following (example):

in routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'
import App from './App';
import LoginContainer from './containers/LoginContainer';
import SidebarLayout from './layouts/SidebarLayout';
import DashboardPage from './pages/Dashboard';
import MembersPage from './pages/Members';
import NotFoundPage from './pages/NotFound';

module.exports = (
<Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/" component={LoginContainer}>
        <Route component={SidebarLayout} className="App__navbar">
            <IndexRoute component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="/members" component={MembersPage} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path="*">
        <IndexRoute component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Route>
</Route>
);
```

In SideBarLayout.js

```
require('semantic-ui-css/semantic.css');
import React from 'react';
import './SidebarLayout.css';

export default class SidebarLayout extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='App__navbar'>
                <XXXContainer />
                <YYYContainer />
            </div>
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

In SidebarLayout.css

```
.App__navbar {
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Now I can click both Navbar and App__navbar using cmd + click and get to the component and class in css respectively. Of course I also tried using a component with parameters like function MyComponent({children, myprop}). You always need to enter proper stylesheet classes in the css file before this works, there is no magic (but maybe a plugin can create this automatically).